# Stackoverflow Style URL's with Friendly_ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I was able to setup friendly_id with one of my models (categories), but I need help with setting up with another model.

Basically I want the URL's to be something like this: `domain.com/129121/title-of-post` where 129121 is the ID  of the post.

I tried doing this by updating the `to_param` but it did not work (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/7265).

Im not sure how to get SO style links working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar and come up with

```
 def slug
  name.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")  # you can change name to the attribute that holds your title
 end

 def to_param
  "#{self.id}-#{slug}"
end
```

Might get you on your way

Comment: I actually wanted a `/` to separate the id and the name. (Look at the URL of stack overflow. I want something like that.)

Comment: there was a reason why i didnt go that far, complications with routes and performance, ill dig out the reasons and let you know

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I knew how to use to_param, but I wanted them to look exactly like SO's since they look cool.